# How can I centralize the dropdown menu and shrink the distance between its submenus?

Tags: html, css

I am relatively new to web development. I am having some inconveniences with the esthetic of the page. I would like to know how can I centralize and make the submenus closer to the parent menu.
I've tried padding, along many other code I've read searching what helped others.
I've read and tried several times unsuccessfully

```css
/* Dropdown menu */
nav ul {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 100px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

        nav ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
        }

nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: black;

}
/* Hide Dropdown by Default*/
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
/* hover */
nav a:hover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #A4E5E0;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
/* Display Dropdown on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: inherit;
}
/* First Tier Dropdown */
nav ul ul li {
    width: 350px;
    float: none;
    display: list-item;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container" style="position:absolute">
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Head Count
                        <ul>
                            <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Agregar nuevo Head Count", "CreateHeadCount", "Home", new { area = "" }, null) </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Editar Head Count", "EditHeadCount", "Home", new { area = "" }, null) </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Actualizar Grupo", "UpdateAllHC", "Home", new { area = "" }, null) </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        SPH
                        <ul>
                            <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("SPH Acumulada", "GetSPH", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)  </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Missing SPH", "MissingSPH", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)  </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Work Orders
                        <ul>
                            <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Returned work orders", "ReturnedWO", "Home", new { area = "" }, null) </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Work orders without movement", "GetWOWithoutMov", "Home", new { area = "" }, null) </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Weekly Efficiency
                        <ul>
                            <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Add Weekly Efficiency", "DowngradeTierLevel", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Overall look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAAsj.png)

Comment: can you provide some working example?

Comment: Check the image link I added above now

Comment: Please go read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting, and format your code in a way that we can _use_ it, without having to remove quote formatting from every line manually, or other such hindrances.

Comment: @maria the issue is very simple to resolve but i need to check the actuall wotking code so I can debug and resolve.

Comment: @CBroe now I understood how to do it.

Comment: @SahilDhir the code is really long, and I am not sure if I can completely share it due to confidentiality.

Comment: @Maria you css code has some wrong position:absolute causing all this issues

Comment: Your sub-menu `ul` have a margin of 100px in all four directions. If you want less distance between the main menu items and the sub menus, then you should start by reducing that. And familiarize yourself with how the developer tools built into modern browsers work, if you don't know yet - _inspecting_ elements and figuring out what margins, paddings etc. come from where exactly, is rather easy using those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a [codesandbox with a solution based on your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-75397954-solved-7betsp)
Your main problem is the usage of position absolute everywhere and forgetting to set the position using top/left properties. Also margin at bad level mishelp you.

```
  /* Dropdown menu */
  nav ul {
    padding: 0px;
    /*margin: 100px; /*why ?*/
    /*margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0;*/
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    position: relative;
  }

  nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: black;
  }
  /* Hide Dropdown by Default*/
  nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  /* hover */
  nav a:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #a4e5e0;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    display: block;
    /*position: absolute;*/ /* not needed */
    left: 0;
  }
  /* Display Dropdown on Hover */
  nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: inherit;
  }
  /* First Tier Dropdown */
  nav ul ul li {
    width: 350px;
    float: none; /* remove it */
    /*display: list-item;*/
    /*position: absolute; /* ul must be absolute, not li*/
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }
```